How to select URL parameter and exclude all the other stuff that comes after it?
I'm using dynamic text based on a URL parameter. Basically, the goal is to select the first word in the URL parameter and insert it into a paragraph. However, in my current code, it selects the first word in the URL parameter and everything else that comes after it.
Destination URL is like this:
https://example.com/?ref=firstWord/blah/blah/blah
I want to select just the firstWord (excluding /blah/blah/blah) and insert it into a paragraph. I should mention that firstWord is a variable wildcard-type of word.
Here's the code that selects the firstWord and everything else after it:


var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var firstWord = url.searchParams.get("ref");
document.getElementById("firstWord").innerHTML = firstWord;
Welcome to <p id='firstWord'></p>



Here's my attempt to select just firstWord and discard /blah/blah/blah:


var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var firstWord = url.searchParams.get("ref").split('/');
document.getElementById("firstWord").innerHTML = firstWord;
Welcome to <p id='firstWord'></p>



However, this does not exclude /blah/blah/blah. Instead it inserts it into the paragraph like so:
Welcome to firstWord,blah,blah,blah. I don't understand where the commas came from.

Will it always be the first item after the ?? I would split the string by "?", then by "/"

@mykaf
Yes, it's always the first param. Thank you.

The code is already successfully getting the parameter value from the URL.  You'd just need to apply whatever custom logic you want to apply to that value.  For example, given the value shown, you could split the string on "/" and take the first one from those results.  Terms like "and other strings" or "discard everything else" are pretty vague.  How you define the logic of what to do with that parameter value is up to you.

@David My code selects mainParam/blah/blah/blah. But I don't want it to select the whole thing. I only want it to select mainParam and discard /blah/blah/blah.

@John: Which means you have a string value, and you want to extract a substring from that string value.  What specific logic do you use to determine that substring?  (For example, in the value shown you appear to want everything up to but not including the first "/" character)  And what attempt have you made to parse a substring from the string you have?  What isn't working as expected in that attempt?

So split mainParam on "/" and get the first element of the array.

@mykaf Yes. And thank you.

@David Yes, I want to include everything between = and the first /. I read about split function but don't know how to incorporate it.

So split() will take a string an separate it into an array, using the delimited provider to determine where to separate the string. Then you can take the array element that you want to keep and manipulate it or split it further, as needed.

@mykaf I just tested it by inserting .split('/') into the second line like so: var mainParam = url.searchParams.get("ref").split('/');. Didn't work though. Sorry, I'm such a noob. I'm gonna experiment with it some more. Thanks for your help.

"Didn't work though" What did happen? Was there an error in the dev console? Did it give an unexpected result? Please update your question to include how you tried this so we can have the full exact context.

@John: If you look at the documentation for split() you'll see that it returns an array.  If you want the first element from an array, do you know how to get that?  (Hint: The answer below demonstrates.)

@mykaf I've updated my original post as to what happens when I use split('/') alongside my current code.

So you're forcing the array (firstWord) into a string when you set it to the innerHTML. But it's definitely an array. Are you familiar with arrays and how to manipulate them?

@David Yes, I see that I'm supposed to use split('/') function in order to split at the first occurrence of /. The problem I ran into is the syntax.

What's your syntax problem?

@John: "I don't understand where the commas came from." - Because you're outputting the entire array to the page, instead of just the first element of that array.  The answer below demonstrates two ways of getting the first element from the array.  The first approach is to surround the variable name in the declaration with square brackets to destructure the array into that variable.  The second approach is to specify the index of the element after splitting the string into the array.  Either approach does the same thing.  Please try using the answer below.

@David I can't use const because my code is var. The firstWord is a variable wildcard-type of word.

@John: What stops you from using var then?  (Though for any modern JavaScript const and let are recommended.)  What does that have to do with the problem?  What is "a variable wildcard-type of word"?  It's really not clear where you're stuck at this point, and it looks like you're just not familiar with what an array is or how to use one.  If that's the case then before implementing this code you should probably go through some JavaScript tutorials.  Arrays are a fundamental structure of all (or at least most) programming languages.

@David I've explained my objective very clearly. Yes, Evert demonstrates how to extract the first element from the array. What I don't know is how to inject his code into my code.

@John: In your second code snippet above, either (1) surround the variable declaration with square brackets to destructure the array, or (2) append [0] after the call to split to select the first element of the array.  Exactly as suggested in the answer below, and throughout the comment thread above.  If you try either of the approaches suggested, what happens?

document.getElementById("firstWord").innerHTML = firstWord[0];

@David It worked. Thank you.

const ref = url.searchParams.get("ref");
const [justTheFirstPart] = ref.split('/');

or:
const justTheFirstPart = ref.split('/')[0];

Will fail if mainParam is undefined.

Appreciate the answer, but it didn't work for me. In my case, mainParam is a variable word, varying in length.

@John that doesn't matter. It's just a variable name. You can name it something else.

Got it. Thank you.
